# Android: How to find which tab is active in a tablayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am currently working on a simple android application.

There is a login page, and as it is possible to login as a Driver or as a Passenger, there are different tabs in that page.

I have to use the same "email" and "password fields a, and the same login button. basically the only thing that change is the subtitle

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LhAZABk.png]

I need to figure out which tab is active when the login button is pressed, in order to use the right login options and send the user to the right place.

Here are parts of the code:

Login layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.domain.myname.schoolproject.Login_Screen">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Nom_Application"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Connexion"
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:src="@drawable/carleft"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Description_icône" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:src="@drawable/carright"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Description_icône"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLeft" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtMail"
        android:hint="@string/Mail"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edtPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:hint="@string/Password"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnConnexion"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Inscription"
        android:id="@+id/btnInscription"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#0006ff"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onInscription" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_login_screen"
        android:id="@+id/btnConnexion"
        android:background="#15c100"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnInscription"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onConnexion"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtError"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="#d60c00"
        android:singleLine="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

One of the fragment layouts

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.domain.myname.schoolproject.Login_Screen">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Driver"
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The pageAdapter class

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {

        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return new LoginDriver();
            case 1:
                return new LoginPassenger();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Driver);
            case 1:
                return context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Passenger);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And from the LoginScreen class, I need to find out the current tab in this event

```
public void onConnexion(View view) {
    android.content.Intent getNextScreen;

    String mail = txtMail.getText().toString();
    String pass = txtPass.getText().toString();
    //Identification(this.)



    getNextScreen = new android.content.Intent(this, Summary_Driver_Screen.class);

    startActivity(getNextScreen);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help. I can give more details if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[getSelectedTabPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#getSelectedTabPosition()) does exactly what you need: returning the current index of the selected tab.

Comment: getSelectedTabPosition does not exist. do i have to use something.getSelectedTabPosition?

Comment: It is a method of your `TabLayout`

Comment: how to get tabname of tabselected

Comment: @SanikaKadam - `pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition())`

Comment: use TabSelected Event